# C#: Recursive Generics

Tags: c#, .net, typescript, generics

Is it possible define recursive generics in C#? Or more specific: can this code (TypeScript) be translated to C#?

```
type U<T> = (a: U<T>) => T;

function f<T>(a: U<T>): T {
    return a(a)
}

function g<T>(a: T): boolean {
    return false
}

console.log(f(g))
```

The type `U<T>` uses itself in its definition.

Thank you

Comment: can you describe what you are trying to achieve with this kind of recursion, and what have you tried?

Comment: It's possible; generic recursion and inheritance can be used to make [a c# compiler bomb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/69200/39452)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the TypeScript correctly, this is probably the closest equivalent in C#:

```
delegate T U<T>(U<T> a);

static void Main() {
    T f<T>(U<T> a) => a(a);
    bool g<T>(T a) => false;

    Console.WriteLine(f<bool>(g));
}
```

We must explicitly supply a type to `f`, since a delegate conversion is necessary and the compiler won't do it automatically. We can avoid this if we make `g` an actual delegate instance rather than a local function, although this solution lacks symmetry :

```
static void Main() {
    T f<T>(U<T> a) => a(a);
    U<bool> g = a => false;

    Console.WriteLine(f(g));
}
```

We cannot directly make `f` a delegate, since we'd have to leave the generic parameter open, which C# doesn't allow.